# Display data on selecting a particular value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I wish to create a layout where i get a list of items/name from database, and when i click on a name/item from that list information reated to that name/item should get displayed
For this i divided the page into 2 half. The first half has a list of data and the second half will be displaying the details of a particular data. view would be something like this:

[sample view of the required data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVxcC.png)

code that i am using till now is:

```
<div class="panel-body">
<?php
    $sql="SELECT * from `profile` ";
    $result= mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo $row['firstname'];
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
?>
</div>

<div class="col-md-9">
    <section class="tile">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            //display data here after clicking on a particular name/item
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Can anyone please tell me how i can carry the id from left view to right view and display data according to it.

Comment: use `onclick` event from first view, get the data of respective user through ajax and finally update the content of right view.

Comment: fire a ajax call on onclick event...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <?php
    $sql="SELECT * from `profile` ";
    $result= mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {?>
            // Here, i'm assuming 'id' as primary key column. Change according to your requirement.
            <span class='ListId' data-id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
                <?php echo $row['firstname'];?>
            </span> 
          <?php echo "<br>";?>
        <?php }
    }?>
</div>

<div class="col-md-9">
  <section class="tile">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <div class='ShowData'>
            //display data here after clicking on a particular name/item
        </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>

<script>
    $('.ListId').click(function(){
        var Id=$(this).attr('data-id');
        $.ajax({url:"Ajax_ShowDetails.php?Id="+Id,cache:false,success:function(result){
            $(".ShowData").html(result);
        }});
    });
</script>
```

**Ajax_ShowDetails.php** (Create one page of any name. But, make sure if you change page name here, you have to change in `<script></script>` tag too because both are related).
In this page, Through 'Id' fetch all details.

```
<?php

$Id=$_GET['Id'];

Through this '$Id', fetch all required details. It will automatically sit in 'ShowData' Div.

// Write Your Query

?>
```

Comment: when i am clicking on the first item of the list in the left hand part, the Ajax_ShowDetails.php is running and i am getting correct id as result but if i click on any other item from the list the script is not running

Comment: Hi @darcy. It was my mistake. Please change 1) `<span id='ListId'></span>` to `<span class='ListId'></span>` 2)`$('#ListId').click(function(){` to `$('.ListId').click(function(){` Because `Id` is unique.

Comment: I edited my answer. Please check it. Upper comment will let you know what changes to do @darcy

Answer (score 1):

On click of user, take the id of the user, and call an ajax by passing the user id.

With that is fetch the data from database and display where you want to display that.

Give `class="users"` for the list of users.

```
$(document).on("click",".users",function(e){          
var url = "path to php file";
var id = "id of the user.";
     $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:'POST',
        data:{id:id}
        success:function(data){          
            $('.table-responsive').html(data);
        }
     });
 e.preventDefault(); 
 return false;
});
```

Comment: items on left hand side are not getting clicked and the id is not getting passed

Comment: have you loaded jquery library??

Answer (score 0):

You can make a **data attribute** to identify which user is clicked and then you can use that id for what ever you want.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                        {
                            echo"<div class='users' data-id='".$row['id']."'>";
                            echo $row['firstname'];
                            echo"</div>"; 
                        }
```

and in js do like this..

```
$(document).on("click",".users",function(e){          
var url = "getInfo.php";//your file
var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
     $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:'POST',
        data:{id:id}
        success:function(data){          
           //you will get all infor
           $(".table-responsive").html(data);//make layout according to your requirement  
        }
     });
 e.preventDefault(); 
 return false;
});
```

**Edited:** Check this its working(clicked)

```js
   

$(document).on("click",".users",function(e){ 
      alert($(this).attr("data-id"));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='users' data-id='user123'>
  User 123
</div>
```

Comment: any error ,explain what you are doing. did you replace "getInfo.php" which your file name.

Comment: Anand Singh i am not getting any error, the items are not getting clicked so the ajax is not able to execute